# Ubuntu Studio 20.10 Loopback / Monitor Microphone Realtime

Tags: usb, microphone, jack, input, realtime

How could I further reduce delay?

Audacity seems to add a bit more delay. So I have routed input to output, and enabled realtime, through QjackCtl. I still notice quite a bit of delay.

I am at the moment using a Superlux e205u USB microphone, and have headphones connected to them as well as using them for recording.